# builder.setAutoCancel(true) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, android-notifications

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setContentText("Click here");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Test", pendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this).notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    });
}
```

I also experimented by removing builder.addAction(), but when I click on the notification nothing works. How can we lead the user to a particular activity when the notification is clicked upon without adding an action? Also, in either case; I'm unable to dismiss the notification unless I manually slide to remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Using `setContentIntent` should solve your problem:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

**full code :**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setContentText("Click here");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Test", pendingIntent);
            builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    });
```

**Update :**

```
builder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: setContentIntent() works, thanks. But how to dismiss the notification exactly the same way when we have added an action, and the action is clicked upon?

Comment: It's not working. 
builder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;